# Calculate mean of row after X entries

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the mean of all values in a row after e.g. 5 entries in this particular row, this leads to different "start" points of mean-calculation. As soon as there are 5 values in a row the mean of the values should be calculated.
Note: There might be some NaNs in the rows which should not count in the 5 entries, I want to use valid values only.

Example if I wanted to calculate after e.g. 5 entries:

```
Index   D1    D2   D3   D4   D5   D6   D7
  1     NaN   NaN   2    3    4   5    6
  2     1      1    2    3    4   5    6
  3     2      1   NaN   3    4   5    6
  4     NaN   NaN  NaN   3    4   5    6
```

My desired output looks like this:

```
Index   D1    D2   D3   D4   D5   D6   D7
  1     NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  4
  2     NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  2.2  2.66 3.14
  3     NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   3   3.5
  4     NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I was trying to use the .count method, but I got NaNs in all cells using my code below:

```
B = A.copy()
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(A.shape[1]):
        if A.iloc[i,0:j].count() > 5:
            B.iloc[i,j] = B.iloc[i,0:j].sum()/B.iloc[i,0:j].count() 
        else:
            B.iloc[i,j] = np.nan
```

Edit: 
It looks like I found a solution: Changing inside the forloop:

```
# Old version
B.iloc[i,j] = B.iloc[i,0:j].sum()/B.iloc[i,0:j].count() 
# New version
B.iloc[i,j] = A.iloc[i,0:j].sum()/A.iloc[i,0:j].count()
```

If someone has a faster/prettier solution let me know anyways, I don't really like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is the expanding mean:

```
df.loc[:, 'D1':].expanding(5, axis=1).mean()
```

I'm not sure `Index` is a column or an index in your dataframe. If it's the index, you can remove the `loc[...]` call.

Comment: It is indeed the index, thank you! I will try this way :) EDIT: It worked, Thank you for the solution, code looks cleaner and faster :)